# Bash script for printing a part of line from a file which is in n directories

Tags: bash

How do I write a bash script for printing a part of a line from a file that is present in number of directories? My `file` has 80 lines and I want to print a part of the 80th line to another file `prin`. This file is present in *n* directories.

I tried

```
sed -n '80,24p; 24q' A >> "value"
```

where  `value` is the file name with the printed line parts from `A`, but I want to run it on a number of directories.

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you post samples of Input_file and directory structure examples, it will be really great for us to help you, cheers.

Comment: My file is A, then it would be :
A/B/home
A/C/home with a number of possibilities.
I guess this what you asked for!

Comment: I tried this 
sed -n '80,24p; 24q' A >> "value"
value is the file name with the printed line parts from A. But i want to run it on a number of directories

Comment: You should [edit] the question to add your example input and expected output. I've added what you've tried from the comments already.

Comment: Thank you! this is the first Time I'm asking a question! i'll make it right nextt time on!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below command

```
sed -n 80p file.txt & sed -n 80p prin.txt
```